# kafka + describe views for ConsumerGroupCommand

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

we checked the *kafka consumer groups* with describe with `kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --group gonb_cars --describe --bootstrap-server kafka1:6667`

we have 3 Kafka cluster with Kafka version - 1.X

while Kafka client is installed on machine - `192.9.200.17`

what is interesting from the output is that `CLIENT-ID - consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f` , is serve all topic partitions , but I don't sure about this

what I expect to get is much more of consumer groups as `consumer-1 , consumer-2 , consumer-3 ,` etc

but I share the following details in order to understand if the configuration that I described is normal or maybe wrong ?

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --group gonb_cars --describe --bootstrap-server kafka1:6667

GROUP           TOPIC                    PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                     HOST            CLIENT-ID
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 97         284837505       284851115       13610           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 75         284834918       284848533       13615           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 55         284836247       284849847       13600           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 71         284837402       284851021       13619           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 193        284834839       284848444       13605           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 185        284834685       284848173       13488           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 19         284837151       284850648       13497           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 42         284835514       284849130       13616           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 59         284834551       284848159       13608           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 135        284836249       284849732       13483           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 117        284836386       284849734       13348           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 26         284837584       284850604       13020           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 50         140315368       140328987       13619           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 20         284837585       284851179       13594           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 131        140315302       140328818       13516           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 163        284836297       284849352       13055           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 155        284835748       284849365       13617           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 147        140315792       140329251       13459           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 36         284835913       284849373       13460           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 199        140315144       140328749       13605           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 175        284837539       284851148       13609           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 14         284836853       284850469       13616           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 115        284835166       284848811       13645           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 113        140315598       140329112       13514           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 84         140315725       140329237       13512           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 29         284834374       284847530       13156           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 33         284835149       284848741       13592           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 100        284835550       284849150       13600           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 88         284606827       284619888       13061           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 12         284836044       284849656       13612           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 121        284835889       284849491       13602           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 129        284835787       284849073       13286           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 189        284837129       284850596       13467           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 8          284837481       284850618       13137           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 104        140315623       140328901       13278           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 45         284837201       284850805       13604           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 81         284834957       284848440       13483           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 169        284836263       284849417       13154           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 132        140316122       140329240       13118           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 145        284835688       284849193       13505           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 181        284835218       284848860       13642           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 151        284835087       284848590       13503           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 93         284543058       284556571       13513           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 11         284834392       284847881       13489           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 159        284835770       284849285       13515           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 179        284837419       284850682       13263           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 62         284836901       284850398       13497           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 109        284835710       284849311       13601           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 171        284835340       284848886       13546           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 49         284835619       284849265       13646           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 78         284837225       284850826       13601           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 66         284837838       284850975       13137           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 69         284835066       284848551       13485           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 53         140315424       140329016       13592           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 133        140315359       140328959       13600           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 178        284835829       284849335       13506           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 79         284835854       284849452       13598           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 38         140315261       140328876       13615           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 124        284837984       284851165       13181           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 162        284835399       284849005       13606           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 82         284835704       284849350       13646           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars       cars_data.analist 149        284835242       284848840       13598           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 102        140315734       140329214       13480           

.
.
.

gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 122        284837124       284850732       13608           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 190        284834967       284848468       13501           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 40         284836001       284849172       13171           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 130        140316138       140329176       13038           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 9          284835448       284849067       13619           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 112        284834924       284848526       13602           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 142        140315258       140328869       13611           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 0          140316130       140329235       13105           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 37         140315957       140329125       13168           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 136        284835454       284848628       13174           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 16         140315438       140329085       13647           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 166        140315556       140329157       13601           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 4          140315503       140329002       13499           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 139        284835672       284849275       13603           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 3          140315708       140329199       13491           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 172        140315560       140329155       13595           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 21         284837356       284850976       13620           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 85         284835288       284848787       13499           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 95         284835237       284848252       13015           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 76         284835035       284848642       13607           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 70         140315972       140329153       13181           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 148        284835516       284849163       13647           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 54         284836267       284849889       13622           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 186        284837590       284851070       13480           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 118        140316126       140329147       13021           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 194        284836523       284850118       13595           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 126        284835543       284849162       13619           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 103        284837853       284851019       13166           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 156        284836413       284849881       13468           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
gonb_cars      cars_data.analist 101        284835379       284848892       13513           consumer-1-6d373e02-52bd-4da2-a3d2-abc93b02b48f /192.9.200.17    consumer-1
[root@kafka1 ~]#
```

reference - https://dbmstutorials.com/kafka/kafka-consumer-groups.html

Comment: Maybe it's cut off on your terminal? 200+ partitions is a lot. Or the consumer group rebalanced and there's simply only one active consumer. The source code definitely has no limit applied https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala#L273

Comment: Also, your last question you have Kafka version 2.7. Here you say 1.X... So you do have a more than one cluster?

Comment: yes they are diff clusters

Comment: about your first note - no all lines are the same with the same consumer group !

Comment: 1) Well, have you tried running multiple consumers with the same `group.id` and a different `client.id`, or maybe even more than one topic? 2) Obviously all lines have the same consumer group because this is the group being described in your command that you typed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --group gonb_cars --describe --bootstrap-server kafka1:6667`
will be used to describe *one* consumer group only, i.e `gonb_cars`

The command seems correct and would show the correct result, this particular consumer group has only one consumer in it namely consumer-1.

As per the question, you are looking for multiple consumer groups, which can be seen via the `-—list` parameter.

Comment: so you agree that we have "only one consumer in it namely consumer-1." , is it logical configuration? , or we need to use several of consumers groups

Comment: @jessica You need to provide more details about your consumer clients. Sure, running one consumer is perfectly valid.

Comment: @jessica, will it work ? Definitely. Is it ideal? No. Consumer groups are how multiple instances of the same app share kafka data between them,using the same consumer group id. In your case if consumer1 stops,the pipeline stops. Consumers in a consumer group can be scaled from 0 to no. of partitions in a topic. So if one consumer dies, kafka rebalances and starts sending the data to other members of the same group. If you want same data to be sent to two diff sets of applications, use different consumer groups.

Comment: what for example is the preferred consume groups for instance of 100 partitions

Comment: @jessica Diff consumer groups are used when different sets of app need the same data. Ideally , kafka ensures that same copy of data is sent to *every* consumer group that is reading the topic. Within each such group any one consumer can read it.  Imagine a use case where same topic is required by diff. services, then a consumer group can be dynamically created at any time and read the topic (this is called pub-sub). Now within each such groups there can be multiple consumers , count of which will depend upon your use case and design e.g high availability and consumer efficiency.